# Intervals of a derivative

Tags: functions, derivatives

I'm trying to find the intervals of the derivative of a function that I found on my book but I'm having some troubles understanding it, so I thought of trying to find some help here.

The function is $$
{f(x) = \arcsin(|x^2+3x+3|-1)} 
$$

So I need to find the derivative of this function, study it and find the intervals (where it's increasing and where it's decreasing)

This is the solution:

$$
-\frac{ \left( 2x+3 \right)  }{\sqrt{1-(x^2+3x+3)^2} } \, (-2, -1) $$and$$ \frac{ \left( 2x+3 \right)  }{\sqrt{1-(x^2+3x+1)^2} } \  (-3, -2)(-1, 0)
$$

So the function is decreasing in $[-3, -2]$ and $[-\frac{3}{2}, -1]$ while increasing in $[-2, -\frac{3}{2}]$ and $[-1, 0]$.

Here is where I am having some troubles:

-How do I find those intervals? I know that I need to solve the equations, but I 'm stuck there

-How can I find where the function is decreasing and increasing?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Are you sure of the formula for $f(x)$? It does not correspond to the computation of the derivative.

Comment: Hey! Yes, i always used f(x) for functions!

Comment: That was not my question: the argument of arcsine has a $-1$ at the end, and it disappears  in the denominator of the derivative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that the denominator is ALWAYS positive when it exists, because it's inside a square root.

So now if you look at the numerator, for $-(2x+3)$, for $(-2,-1)$, we see that it's positive when $(2x+3)<0$, so that means f(x) is increasing for $x<\displaystyle -\frac{3}{2}$, or $\left(-2,\displaystyle -\frac{3}{2}\right)$. The function is decreasing when $(2x+3)>0$ and the numerator is negative, which corresponds to the interval $\left(\displaystyle \frac{3}{2}, -1 \right)$.

Now, we can look at the second piece. The numerator is positive, and the function is increasing for $x>\displaystyle -\frac{3}{2}$ and decreasing for $x<\displaystyle -\frac{3}{2}$. Since we know that this function is only defined on $(-1,3)$, this means that f(x) is also increasing on $\left(-1,0 \right)$ and decreasing on $(-3,2)$.

The important thing was to consider each piece by itself, so now your answer is putting those 4 intervals together.

Comment: You must consider the domain of function $f$, which is not $(-1,3)$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since $x^2+3x+3 > 0, x \in \mathbb{R}$, the expression of $f$ is simply $f(x)= \arcsin(x^2+3x+2)$. Now, the domain of $f$ is given by the points that satisfy $-1 \leq x^2+3x+2 \leq 1$. the left inequality is always satisfied, the right inequality is satisfied when $x^2+3x+1 \leq 0$, i.e.
$$
x \in \left[\frac 12 (-3 -\sqrt{5}), \frac 12 (-3 +\sqrt{5}) \right]
$$

Obviously, it does not make sense to analyse the sign of the derivative's expression when we are outside the domain of $f$. Finally, since

$$
f'(x)= \frac{2x+3}{\sqrt{1-(x^2+3x+2)^2}}
$$

you see that the derivative is negative for $x < -\frac 32$ and positive for $x> -\frac 32$, but always remaining in the domain!

Comment: I understood! Thank you!